# Use JavaScript String literal on Java project

Tags: javascript, java, node.js

I'm sending a javascript literal from my app into a server running node. I want to put this string into a java file that I build dynamicly. So my question is how to convert a Javascript literal into a String that can be put used in a Java program.
I tried using String.Raw``, Here is what I actually do:

```
javaString = "${String.raw`${jsLiteral}`.replace('"','\"').replace("'","\'")}";
```

It is not working, because the literal has new lines and that generates Java errors. Thank you!

Comment: as @rsp said, use a JSON library for de/serialization to/from JS/Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not strictly answer your question but what you should really do here is to use JSON instead of inventing your own serialization method. Every JSON-serialized data can be a valid Java string, it is trivial to serialize and trivial to parse.

In Java you can use Google's Gson library:

- [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) on GitHub

but there are also other options.

And in JavaScript there is built-in JSON.parse and JSON.stringify:

- [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) on MDN
- [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) on MDN

Of course you could invent your own serialization like you're trying to do here, but it's usually not worth the hassle.